# How to run batch file through Windows Scheduler running python file outputting plotly plot

Tags: python, command, plotly, scheduler

I have a batch file which runs a python file outputting an interactive plot via Plotly in an html file. Running the file via double-clicking runs just fine, but when running through Windows scheduler, it doesn't work.

Python code producing plotly html:

```
plot(fig,filename='output.html')
```

Batch file running python file:

```
python file.py
```

Double-clicking on batch file works.
Running batch file via Window's Scheduler doesn't work and outputs the following error in the command prompt:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\~\file.py", line 224, in <module> plot(fig,filename='output.html')
   File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\offline\offline.py", line 721, in plot with open(filename, 'w') as f:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'output.html'
```

Any idea why this won't work via Windows Scheduler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

I hadn't set the task in the Task Scheduler to "Run with highest privileges." Checking that box fixed the issue.